# Slider not showing/working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

http://jsfiddle.net/adamadam123/L3Mab/18/

I'm trying to get the Jquery UI Slider to work - you can see the code in jsfiddle.net

I can get the slider to appear but when I've made changes to update the icon that does the sliding (a blue button) it fails:

```
div.chatMessengerWrapper .ui-slider-vertical .ui-slider-handle {
background: url(http://www.staticimages.co/online-dating/chat-contacts-slider-button.png) no-repeat;
height: 36px;
border: none;
width: 16px;
```

}

hopeing someone can have a look and tweak this for me...

Answer (score 0):

I made the following two changes to your fiddle and it works for me, at least under Chrome and FF 15:

1. Added in JQuery UI CSS (under Manage Resources from CDN in the fiddle).
2. Just a cosmetic thing: JQuery UI CSS was adding an outline to the slider handle when it was clicked.

I added the following code

```
  div.chatMessengerWrapper a:focus {
      outline: none;
  }
```

to the CSS to remove it.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/BL5rM/5/